# jquery slideshow want to remoev white screen displayed while changing images

Tags: jquery

I have used the following slideshow on my site. but i don't want the blank white screen that is displayed while changing(fading image). can anyone help me on this?

http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html
http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Give that `<div>` Tag a background-image via css.

e.G. for Slider One (Example 1):

```
#slider {
  background-image: url('/images/my-background-image.png');
}
```

Comment: that's not what i want. it will simply show another background image while changing to next image.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked this question on the linked site aswell in the comment secion.

> any body know how to stop the image stop completely fading out? I want the appearance of a stop frame animation so need the next image to fade in before the previous image fades out. Any ideas?

Then another User responded with:

> i did it by adding one line in s3slider.js as shown below.

You should give it a try, I couldnt test it tough (The feedback in the comments is mostly positive so it seems to work). Posted code by user 'pedro costa':

```
var makeSlider = function() {
        current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)];
        var currNo      = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1
        currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
        var newMargin   = $(element).width() * currNo;
        if(faderStat == true) {
            if(!mOver) {
                $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
                    if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = false;
                            current = items[currNo];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = false;
                            current = items[currNo];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if(!mOver) {
                //added next line
                $(items[(currNo)]).parent().parent().css('background-image', 'url('+$(items[(currNo)]).children("img").attr("src")+')');
                // added previous line
                if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                    $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = true;
                            current = items[(currNo+1)];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = true;
                            current = items[(currNo+1)];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```